# How to add MySQL Server bin path to System Path Variables using Python

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess, system-variable, setx

I have created a automated script to install and start MySQL Server
In which I have last step to add MySQL bin directory to System Variables

Here is snippet of that code:

```
try:
    command = f'setx PATH "%PATH%;{bin_path}"'

    process = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'cmd', '/c', command],
                               shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode == 0:
        print("Directory added to PATH successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Adding directory to PATH failed: {stderr}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

here bin_path is "**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin**"

The code seems to be correct but it is not working
also by executing command in command prompt it does work but in python it is not working
I don't know where i am going wrong

I tried the code mentioned above seems to work through normal command prompt but doesn't work using python subprocess.
I want to solve the Add to PATH issue

Comment: If you install MySQL Server set the check include bin to systempath, then you can save your extra work. This option is recommended.